# Why am i getting an unauthorized message when I use youtube api

Tags: javascript, ajax, youtube

I'm trying to get a list of playlists to display and have my ajax call set up like:

```
function loadData(){


    if(GoogleAuth.currentUser.get().hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE)){
        $.ajax({
            url:'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists',
            data:{
                'key':'AIzaSyD0OY6xhl9gP9CmPXvU-rN-purRDaTrip8',
                'mine':'true',
                'maxResults':'5',
                'part':'snippet,contentDetails'
            },
            sucess:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(data){
                console.log(data.responseText);
            }
        });
    }



}
```

This code runs only after the page has fully loaded and the user has been given the choice to log in. If they do log in a list of playlists should build. I have enabled my api key, made sure my origin is whitelisted, and everything else I can think of. 
however I keep getting this response:

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.parameter",
    "reason": "authorizationRequired",
    "message": "The request uses the \u003ccode\u003emine\u003c/code\u003e parameter but is not properly authorized.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "mine"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "The request uses the \u003ccode\u003emine\u003c/code\u003e parameter but is not properly authorized."
 }
```

I have made sure to wrap the ajax call to ensure that the user is already logged in. So I'm not sure why I am getting this error message. I'm still getting the hang of api calls so please let me know if I forgot to add something to it. From what I can tell from google docs this should be all I need.

Comment: Have you followed this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

[`mine`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list)

> boolean This parameter can only be used in a [properly authorized
>   request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps). Set this parameter's value to true to retrieve a feed of the
>   authenticated user's activities

Properly authorized requests means that they implement OAuth 2.0 Authorization
as the link above suggests.
To implement OAuth 2.0 Authorization, please follow the instructions here :

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps